# Validar por caracter en un jTextfield en Java

Tags: java, string, validación

La problemática es que necesito que a la hora de ingresar información de un jtextfield dedicado a la fecha de registro de un articulo sea dd/mm/yyyy y a la hora de escribir envié un mensaje si se salé del formato.

Simplificando, sería que al ingresar datos el 3er y el 6to carácter siempre sean "/".

Comment: Mejor usa un JDateChooser, porque sino estarías esperando que el usuario digite 2 digitos en el día, 2 dígitos para el mes y 4 para el año, si escribe de forma diferente tendrás error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer varias cosas para ayudar al usuario:

1. Usar invite message como placeholder cuando el campo esta vacio, indicando cual seria el formato correcto a ingresar.
2. Validaciones posteriores por codigo.

De todas formas creo que como dice [Joshin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/193364/joshin) lo mejor seria evitar posibles errores de ingreso del usuario final utilizando un JDateChooser.

Si de igual forma decides que quieres usar un textField para ingreso de fecha, podrias ayudarte con la clase MaskFormatter.

```
MaskFormatter dateMask;
try {
dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
dateMask.setPlaceholderCharacter('/');
dateMask.setValidCharacters("0123456789");
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

}